# Android OpenGL Rotate cube in the direction of touch movement

Tags: android, opengl-es, rotation, cube, motion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Visually correct rotation with OpenGl and touch screen capabilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207805/visually-correct-rotation-with-opengl-and-touch-screen-capabilities)

I have a cube which I want to rotate in the same direction I am moving my finger while touching. I do know how to get current touch movement and use those values to rotate the cube, but that's not what I want.

This is what I am currently using:

```
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        mx = me.getX();
        my = me.getY();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        x_diff = mx - me.getX();
        y_diff = my - me.getY();
        mx = me.getX();
        my = me.getY();
        this.rot_x -= y_diff;
        this.rot_y -= x_diff;
        break;
```

Rotation:

```
gl.glRotatef(rot_x, 1, 0, 0);
gl.glRotatef(rot_y, 0, 1, 0);
gl.glRotatef(rot_z, 0, 0, 1);
```

Comment: You'll find many similar questions around here, such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207805/visually-correct-rotation-with-opengl-and-touch-screen-capabilities

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution. The correct way to do it was implementing an ArcBall rotation.

NeHe OpenGL Tutorial: http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/arcball_rotation/19003/
Java port: http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/jogl/arcball-rotation-nehe-tutorial-jogl-port.html

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify what it is that you're not happy with with your current implementation, but one idea could be to use a VelocityTracker and assign a 3-Dimensional speed to your cube based on the touch velocity, and then make the cube decelerate slowly back to a standstill as you stop moving your finger. It would give the interaction a more natural feel.

Comment: That's not quite that I was asking. Here's an example: Currently I have it like this: for example after I've rotated the object 180 degrees along x-axis and then try to rotate it along y, it rotates in the opposite direction. What I want to do is to make it rotate always in the same direction as the touch movement.